Return ownership from closure after thread finised in Rust
I am learning Rust and am now taking a look at threads. I am trying to convert the following snippet into a parallelized execution:
fn main() {
    let mut data: Vec<usize> = (1..22).collect();

    for d in &mut data {
        *d *= 99;
    }
}

Since the processing of each element is completely independent from the others, this should be easy to parallelize. So I wrote the following code which splits the vector into N_THREADS parts and then gives each part to a thread to do the processing:
use std::thread;

const N_THREADS: usize = 8;
const N_ELEMENTS: usize = 2*N_THREADS;

fn main() {
    let mut data: Vec<usize> = (1..N_ELEMENTS).collect();

    let mut threads = vec![];
    for n_thread in 0..N_THREADS {
        let thread_fn = move || {
            for d in &mut data[n_thread*(N_ELEMENTS/N_THREADS)..(n_thread+1)*(N_ELEMENTS/N_THREADS)] {
                *d *= 99
            }
        };
        let thread_handle = thread::spawn(thread_fn);
        threads.push(thread_handle);
    }
    // Now wait for the threads to finish.
    for t in threads {
        t.join().unwrap();
    } // I need each `t` to return the ownership of its respective piece of `data` here!
    
    do_something_else(data);
}

How can I get the ownership of data back after all the threads have finished, so then I can do_something_else(data)?

TL;DR. Just use rayon.

This wouldn't work even without do_something_else(data); because you attempt to move data multiple times using move ||.

Also, you can't mutably borrow an object for multiple threads. But for immutable borrows, maybe thread::scope could help.

@aedm You should be able to use scoped threads with split_at_mut in order to create per-worker non-overlapping borrows.

@Masklinn Right, good workaround. :) Thanks.

@aedm chunks_mut is an other option to avoid dealing with boundary / edge cases in split_at_mut.

Leaving aside just using Rayon which does that for you.

So I wrote the following code which splits the vector into N_THREADS parts and then gives each part to a thread to do the processing:

Have you even tried compiling your code? Because does not and can not work, on the first iteration data would get moved in to the first thread you create, then the second thread tries to acquire a moved-from value, which is illegal.
And even if that worked, you can't Index out multiple mutable slices like that, the compiler can't know the slices are non-overlapping. That's why slices have a bunch of split*_mut methods to split mutable borrows. Nor can regular non-scoped threads borrow from their lexical scope.
What you can do is Vec::split_off the source vector into sub-vecs which can be moved into the workers, although that allocates a vector per worker.

How can I get the ownership of data back after all the threads have finished, so then I can do_something_else(data)?

Well join will return whatever the thread callback returns, so you could use that, have each thread return its (updated) sub-vector, then join the vectors back.
A better option (again, ignoring rayon) would be to bypass the entire thing, use scoped threads, and borrow from the original. This requires using some form of mut splitting to give each thread a mutable non-overlapping slice:
use std::thread;

const N_THREADS: usize = 8;
const PER_THREAD: usize = 2;
const N_ELEMENTS: usize = PER_THREAD*N_THREADS;

fn main() {
    let mut data: Vec<usize> = (1..N_ELEMENTS).collect();
    
    println!("{:?}", data);
    thread::scope(|s| {
        for t in data.chunks_mut(PER_THREAD) {
            s.spawn(move || {
                for d in t {
                    *d *= 99;
                }
            });
        }
        // no need to join by hand, because `scope` implicitly joins the scoped threads and we work in-place
    });
    println!("{:?}", data);
}

PS: note that data is not N_ELEMENTS long, it's N_ELEMENTS-1 (aka it only has 15 elements): Rust's normal ranges are half-open, so 1..N_ELEMENTS goes from 1 to 15 not 1 to 16.
PPS: here's the code with Rayon instead:
use rayon::prelude::*;

const N_THREADS: usize = 8;
const PER_THREAD: usize = 2;
const N_ELEMENTS: usize = PER_THREAD*N_THREADS;

fn main() {
    let mut data: Vec<usize> = (1..N_ELEMENTS).collect();
    
    println!("{:?}", data);
    data.par_iter_mut().for_each(|d| *d *= 99);
    println!("{:?}", data);
}

